# Is JSF using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets

I am learning JSF and I have some questions regarding it. I know JSF is a UI framework for making pages and I am using it at the moment and successfully been able to make zome. However I don't understand if JSF is built on JSP, so to write your own components you need to know JSP. Or is this a completly another technology? I have not a strong foundation in Servlet/JSP programming and I wonder if I need to read anout that first? What are the best places to learn apart from the Core JavaServerFaces book? If i should learn servlet and jsp as well which books should i start reading?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of JSF 2.0, which is part of Java EE 6, released at december 2009 (over 2 years ago already), JSP is been **deprecated** as view technology and replaced by Facelets, a XML based view technology. See also the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) (emphasis mine):

> The term Facelets refers to the view declaration language for JavaServer Faces technology. JavaServer Pages (JSP) technology, previously used as the presentation technology for JavaServer Faces, does not support all the new features available in JavaServer Faces in the Java EE 6 platform. **JSP technology is considered to be a deprecated presentation technology for JavaServer Faces.** Facelets is a part of the JavaServer Faces specification and also the preferred presentation technology for building JavaServer Faces technology-based applications.

As to preparing the basic knowledge before learning JSF, make sure that you know and understand at least HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Servlets and XML. HTTP, because you need to understand its stateless nature. HTML, CSS and JavaScript, because that's what JSF code ultimately produces, especially HTML forms is important, JSF is geared towards form based applications. Servlets, because that's where the JSF framework is built on top of. XML, because that's where Facelets is based on.

#### See also:

- [Our JSF tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: Thank you, so JSP is not used if JSF 2.0 if I want to do low level things I don't need to understand that? However servlets I need to understand obviously. Any book recommendations on that?

Comment: Start at [our servlets tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). At the bottom you can find several links to good learning resources. Also, the "Frequently Asked Questions" sections contains links to answers worth reading to understand the stuff better.

Comment: Awesome thanks, so just to be sure, I do not need to read on JSP to do low level tasks in JSF when I become better and want to do things that is beyond what is provided by components and the framework?

Comment: Just the basics, it's not really that hard. Make sure that you clear your mindset from JSP when you're about to learn Facelets, otherwise it'll only confuse your mindset as Facelets is entirely different.